# Symfony 3.3 can't find Doctrine annotations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony 3.3 it works great in local but online it shows me this error

```
Warning: class_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'ORM\Entity' not found or invalid function name in /htdocs/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php on line 145

Warning: class_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'ORM\Table' not found or invalid function name in /htdocs/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php on line 145

Warning: class_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity' not found or invalid function name in /htdocs/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php on line 145
```

Nothing special with my code but it seem that there is a problem with annotations
My entity City start like that

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * City
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CityRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="city")
 */
class City
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

}
```

Also in dev mod, it can't show me the profiler and the issue it's also always linked to the annotations.
Please Help

Comment: What's the PHP version?

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.32 I think it's ok for Symfony 3.3

Comment: do you have it installed with composer? then your files are still there where they are missing? /htdocs/vendor/doctrine/.... ? 
If yes then you autoloader is damaged. If the files are missing then your make "composer install" on your shell

Comment: Yes, I used composer to install Symfony in local then I send them manually to the server I resend vendor/doctrine/ many times so I don't think I miss something in this bundle.
Wich autoloader you mean because there is no autoloader under /app and I think this is a new update

Comment: I can't use composer online because even the toolbar not working but in local everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

Probably in your server opcache is enabled and  opcache.load_comments is disabled
http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.load-comments